# mostrar una imagen con URL desde una variable con react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo una aplicacion en React, en la cual necesito mostrar la imagen llamada **dice1.jpg** (solo en el caso 1 del swith), pero no logro hacerlo, cuando paso su valor por consola me muestra la dirección correctamente.

```
import react, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const RollTheDice = () => {
  const [getValue, setValue] = useState("");
  const [getDice, setDice] = useState("");

  function Roll() {

    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

    switch (value.toString()) {
      case "1":
        setDice("../img/dice1.jpg");
        break;
        case "2":
        setDice("⚁");
        break;
        case "3":
        setDice("⚂");
        break;
        case "4":
        setDice("⚃");
        break;
        case "5":
        setDice("⚄");
        break;
        case "6":
        setDice("⚅");
        break;
    }
    setValue(value);
  }

  return(
  <div>
    <h1>Presione el boton para girar el dado</h1>
    <button onClick={() => Roll()}>Girar el dado</button>
    <h2>
      El resultado es: <b>{getValue}</b>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <h1>{getDice}</h1>
      <img src={getDice} />
    </p>
  </div>
  );
};
```

Esta imagen es del árbol de archivos, donde se ve cada uno de los componentes y la ubicación de las imágenes. El archivo donde se encuentra el código que les pasé se llama **RollTheDice.js** y está ubicado en la carpeta /src/components, por lo que la direccion relativa a la imagen debe ser **../img/dice1.jpg**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: también solo podrías crear una variable vacía arriba, luego en el `switch` agregas la `url` a la variable y cuando vas a mostrar esa imagen solo llamas la variable, así tendrías la misma variable para cada uno de los `case` y no estas importando una imagen para cada uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya conseguí la solución, importando la imagen y asignándole un nombre (en este caso):

```
import dice1 from "../img/dice1.jpg");
```

Y luego asignar el valor *dice1* a `setDice` de la siguiente manera:

```
 setDice(dice1);
```

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.